# How to load-balance readonly instructions across REDIS slaves?

Tags: redis, haproxy

I've set up REDIS replication (1 master + 2 slaves) along with 3 sentinels and 1 HAProxy load balancer. It works, but except failover I would like to load-balance read-only instructions across slaves. Is it possible using HAProxy? Here is part of my HAProxy config:

```
backend bk_redis
option tcp-check
tcp-check connect
tcp-check send PING\r\n
tcp-check expect string +PONG
tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
tcp-check expect string role:master
tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
tcp-check expect string +OK
server redis_1 localhost:6379 check inter 1s
server redis_2 localhost:6380 check inter 1s
```

This will (as I understand) just redirect all traffic to current master, while I would like to load-balance here.

Comment: It would be easiest to just put two proxies - one for master and one for slaves, and send readonly commands to the slave proxy only.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I wish to load-balance readonly instructions across all node (master and slave) and write only to master (which I am able to)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it would be to have a separate backend for primary and another for slaves.

```
frontend fe_redis
  ... no changes

backend bk_redis
  ... no changes



frontend fe_redis_readonly
  bind *:6380                             # Different port 
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  default_backend bk_redis_readonly

backend bk_redis_readonly
  option tcp-check
  tcp-check connect
  tcp-check send PING\r\n
  tcp-check expect string +PONG
  tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
  tcp-check expect string role:slave      # Verify slave 
  tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
  tcp-check expect string +OK

  server redis_1 localhost:6379 check inter 1s
  server redis_2 localhost:6380 check inter 1s
```

The second part is updating the application to distinguish read requests and send them to the reader backend.